# Different IDEs are giving different output, why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmath

When code is executed in VS Code and OnlineGDB, the outputs are different.

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 2;

    while(i != 0){ 
        sum = sum + pow(10, i); 
        i--;
    }

    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

VS Code
[image]

OnlineGDB
[image]

The output in VS Code gives `109`, but the same code in OnlineGDB gives `110`, which is expected.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `pow` is returning a floating point value. You should not use it for integer exponents.

Comment: `pow(10, i)`  is not for integers. It can return a value 1 less than the expected value like pow(5,2) can return 24 or pow(10,2) can return 99.

Comment: `pow` operates on floating-point numbers and can be inexact. If you want to use it on integers, at least `round()` the result.

Comment: Also, your IDE doesn't matter, only the compiler matters.

Comment: Also when two different compilers give you different output, it is usually not the compilers that are wrong.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: To be fair, *library implementations* tend to be wrong, unfortunately, more often than you'd suspect...

Comment: Reverted the edit inlining the screenshots. We frown on screenshots of code / output in the first place, and all the relevant information was in the Q already. The screenshots just cluttered the Q.

Comment: @DevSolar But to be completely clear `pow(10, 2)` returning `99.999999` is not wrong. Perhaps less than ideal but not wrong.

Comment: @john I was referring to the general case. I've found incorrect behavior in dark corners of the standard library before, and won't be surprised to find it again. I cannot really judge the quality of the math implementation here -- that would be bigoted since I have yet to implement them myself for my own standard lib -- but the standard also guarantees a certain precision of the math functions, plus correct rounding, so this *might* actually be a library defect after all. I wouldn't rule it out prematurely.

Comment: @john That would be a *really bad* quality of implementation, though.

Comment: @Bob__ It seems that in the OP's case some unnamed compiler/standard library is returning `9.999999999` for `pow(10,1)` which is even worse QOI.

Comment: @DevSolar I know... everything has bugs, but I tend to look at my own code first ;)

Comment: @john How can you say it is not wrong? This wrong result may be allowed by the standard, but that doesn't make it right.